# map a website structure

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I'd like to code my own website based on an existing opensource CMS (PrestaShop).
There is some nice functionalities but also a bunch of code I won't need for my website (a simple B2B catalog with no fancy stuff). The CMS uses PHP (very different from what I learned 15 years ago) and .tpl files.
I'm wondering if there is a way to map a website like an .exe in a decompiler such as IDA in order to see relation between files, calls etc? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For me, to "map a website structure" means to generate a sitemap. But anyway...

- You can always analyze the exec flow of an PHP application by looking at the source-code, unless it's protected by IonCube or something.
- You might also get a decent IDE, which indexes the code properly and provides Intellisense / code-completion.
- You might install Xdebug and turn profiling on and then analyse the generated trace log with a tool like Cachegrind, to see the visualization of the execution flow of the application.

[image]

Referencing: http://talks.php.net/show/confoo10/10

- There are also commercial profiling tools available, which provide visualization and perform measurements of an application:  http://blackfire.io/, http://tideways.io/

Comment: that is a beautiful image.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I already started looking in [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd409453.aspx). But I'll definitely have a look at your suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure, if VS provides decent PHP support. Try PHPStorm or Netbeans.